# Почему переменная не принимает новые данные (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется код, который при выборе типа анимации, изменяет `data-animation-out` у элемента `dropdown-container`, здесь все работает, проблемы в другом.

Если после изменения типа анимации зайти в `DOM`, мы увидим, что содержимое
`data-animation-out` действительно изменилось. Но при наведение мышки на `dropdown-container` мы видим лог со старой анимацией.

Получается, что переменная `var dropdown_container = $(this).find('>.dropdown-container');` получив один раз содержимое, дальше отказывается получать новое содержимое (обновляться).

**Вопрос:** в чем проблема и как заставить эту переменную обновлять свое содержимое?

```js
$('#setting-set input').click(function()
    {

        var change_element = $('.dropdown > .dropdown-container');
        change_element.attr('data-animation-in', $(this).val());
        console.log('Log:change-element - ' + $(this).val());
    });

$('.dropdown').hover(
        function()
        {
            var dropdown_container = $(this).find('>.dropdown-container');
            dropdown_container.removeClass('element-hide');
            dropdown_container.animateCss(dropdown_container.data('animation-in'));
            console.log('Log:hover-element - ' + dropdown_container.data('animation-in'));
        },
        function()
        {
            var dropdown_container = $(this).find('>.dropdown-container');
            if(dropdown_container.data('animation-out'))
            {
                dropdown_container.animateCss(dropdown_container.data('animation-out'), function()
                {
                    dropdown_container.addClass('element-hide');
                });
            }
            else
            {
                dropdown_container.animateCss('fadeOut', function()
                {
                    dropdown_container.addClass('element-hide');
                });
            }
        });
        
        
        
        $.fn.extend({
        animateCss: function(animationName, callback)
        {
            var animationEnd = (function(el)
            {
                var animations = {
                    animation: 'animationend',
                    OAnimation: 'oAnimationEnd',
                    MozAnimation: 'mozAnimationEnd',
                    WebkitAnimation: 'webkitAnimationEnd',
                };

                for(var t in animations)
                {
                    if(el.style[t] !== undefined)
                    {
                        return animations[t];
                    }
                }
            })(document.createElement('div'));

            this.addClass('animated ' + animationName).one(animationEnd, function()
            {
                $(this).removeClass('animated ' + animationName);

                if(typeof callback === 'function')
                {
                    callback();
                }
            });

            return this;
        },
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="setting-set">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="setting-set" value="bounceIn">Тип 1<br>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="setting-set" value="flipInX">Тип 2<br>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="setting-set" value="zoomIn">Тип 3<br>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="setting-set" value="fadeInUp">Тип 4<br>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="setting-set" value="lightSpeedIn">Тип 5<br>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="setting-set" value="rotateIn">Тип 6<br>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="setting-set" value="flipInX">Тип 7<br>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" name="setting-set" value="zoomIn">Тип 8<br>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </form>

<div class="dropdown">
  <span class="dropdown-container" data-animation-out="123">HOVER ME</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена.

Изменить:

`change_element.attr('data-animation-in', $(this).val());`

На:

`change_element.data('animation-in', $(this).val());`